# prevent twitter bot from taking over direct messages on page

Tags: twitter, dialogflow-es

Pls, I really need help asap.I have created a dialogflow bot for an institution and it is to integrated into twitter. after following dialogflow's documentation, I managed to place it on the company's official twitter page. but now, I'm having an issue with communicating with the bot. I always have to send a DM or tweet to the page in order to get response from the bot. but, the company uses the same page to receive customer complaints. Please, isn't there anyway that I could host the bot on the page and get users to be able to chat with the bot and/or also with customer care.

Comment: I always have to send a DM or tweet to the page in order to get response from the bot

When you mean I do you mean you the developer?
Are you handling user sessions from your backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can try deploying it on a dummy page for the time being and fixing the issue.

If I'm misunderstanding something here then I'm sorry but from what I can tell, you made a bot and deployed it on the official twitter page but the behaviour was not as expected. This has lead to the bot replying to customers when it wasn't supposed to? I'm sure you're in a hurry but its not perfectly clear but that's what I got from the post

Also, its always better to test on a dummy page before deploying to the official page.